# Sveltekit Load Function not rerun in query change

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

So my goal is to make a checkbox that update URL query **noProduct** from 1 to 0 and vice versa. Then my load function will handle updating data based on the query.
**My problem**: Load function only reruns 1 way depending on the first URL query state. If the first time *url?noProduct=0* and click my checkbox to change it to *url?noProduct=1*, it **runs**, but click my checkbox back to *url?noProduct=0* it will not run so the data will not change back. Clicking again will change it back to *url?noProduct=1* and it runs the load function, but because it has the same data it will not change anything on the page. This is pretty confusing because it says the load function reruns if the URL param or query changes.

```js
// +page.svelte
export let data: PageData
let noProduct: boolean = data.noProduct === 1

const updateNoProduct = () => {
    $page.url.searchParams.set('noProduct', noProduct ? '1' : '0')
    goto(`?${$page.url.searchParams.toString()}`)
}

//svelte
<input 
  type="checkbox"
  class="toggle toggle-md"
  bind:checked={noProduct}
  on:change={updateNoProduct}/>
```

And this is my server load

```js
//+page.server.ts
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({url, locals, cookies, depends}) => {
  if (!locals.collectionMeta) locals.collectionMeta = initCollectionMeta()

  const noProduct: string = url.searchParams.has('noProduct') ? `&noproduct=${url.searchParams.get('noProduct')}` : ''
  const countResult: iCount = await get(`/utils/count?collection=1${noProduct}`, cookies.get('token'))
  const totalItem = countResult.total_collection ?? 0

  return {
    totalItem: totalItem,
    noProduct: Number(url.searchParams.get('noProduct')) ?? 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you are not supposed to modify something like `$page.url` and I would not try it either.

The code works as expected when creating a new, full URL:

```js
const updateNoProduct = () => {
    const url = new URL($page.url);
    url.searchParams.set('noProduct', noProduct ? '1' : '0');
    goto(url);
}
```