# In Sveltekit how can I solve a reactivity issue to a url searchParams change?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using Svelte(4.0.5) with Sveltekit(1.20.4) and I have a reactivity issue with the URL search params changes.
It works, but only once every two changes.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { page } from '$app/stores';

  let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  let seed: string | undefined;
  $: {
    seed = $page.url.searchParams.get('id') ?? undefined;
    console.log('1', 'new seed - redrawing', seed);
    draw();
  }

  onMount(() => {/*...*/})

  const draw = () => { /* Draw into a canvas using the seed */ }
  const randomize = async () => {
    const newSeed = Math.random() + '';
    $page.url.searchParams.set('id', newSeed);
    await goto(`?${$page.url.searchParams.toString()}`);
    console.log('2', 'new seed - url', newSeed, seed);
  }
</script>

<canvas bind:this={canvas} on:click={randomize} />
```

So, the first click on `randomize` works fine.
But a second click will never `console.log('1')`.
A third click will be fine.
A fourth click same issue as the second click.
And so on and on.

I'm struggling to pin point where is this reactivity issue coming from.

Comment: Possibly duplicate/same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75321905/546730